# Trying to query multiple posts with WP_Query

Tags: wordpress, loops, while-loop

I have a custom field in my posts so the admin can enter a list of specific post ids they want included for the related content section in the sidebar. I am trying to insert the variable into my wp_query_object but it is only querying the first item.

When I echo the $related_vids variable it displays the ids I entered into the custom field: 45,14,10.

Any help with what I'm doing wrong would be awesome. I feel like I'm close but I've hit the wall.

```
<?php $related_vids = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_3_fieldID_2_numInSet_0', true);
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => array( $related_vids ) ) );
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `array( $related_vids )` actually creates an array that contains 1 element: `["45,14,10"]` and not an array that contains 3 elements: `[45, 14, 10]`

What you need is `explode( ', ', $related_vids )`

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I had to modify it slightly to work right but it got me in the right direction. I realized that with the explode function I also needed to include a separator in addition to the string. I also had to have spaces between my post ids so there was something to explode.

In the end I used : explode(" ",$related_vids)

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  I edited my answer to include the extra parameter in the `explode` invocation.